# App crash on 4.0 but not on 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I trying to fix a strange bugg. People with IOS 4 can't even start my app after the update before it crashes. IOS 5 devices works great.

The things that comes to mind that I added in the last update is blocks. But block should work on ios4, right?

IOS 4.3 simulator works great, but a 4.2.1 3GS crashes on the dispatch_async code below.

I know there isn't much info here, but any suggestion would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance

```
1.         
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^(void) 
                       {
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) 
                                          {


2. 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^
     {
         myView.alpha = 0; 
     }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCD dispatch_after call causing SIGBUS signal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182453/gcd-dispatch-after-call-causing-sigbus-signal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198977/1155387) The problem is `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`.