# UIImage Using dispatch_async Working on Simulator(iOS 5.1) but not on Device (iOS 4.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, multitasking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App crash on 4.0 but not on 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257006/app-crash-on-4-0-but-not-on-5-0)

In My iPhone App need to download image form server so using this code but this working fine on simulator(iOS 5.1) but not on real device (iOS 4.2).please have a look.

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 260, 160)];
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myImageURL.com/image.png"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        });
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Why Guys You are down grading the Question ?

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I suspect it is the lack of information.  "It doesn't work" is not very diagnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the third time I've answered this same question... `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is only available on iOS 5.0+

[App crash on 4.0 but not on 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257006/app-crash-on-4-0-but-not-on-5-0)

Comment: Yes man i just found it and You i was editing my Questions.But please Clear my the difference between Giving and Integer value instead of DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND ?

Comment: `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is just a compile time constant. You should use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`; using its value won't add the feature to iOS 4.

Comment: @Keithbunts iOS 4.2 doesn't know how to handle that constant, so use one of the others instead.