# Facebook SDK 3.0 crash on device using iOS 4.2

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios4

I have an odd issue on an iPod Touch running iOS 4.2.1 where my app will crash when trying to display a `FBProfilePictureView` using the Facebook 3.0 SDK.

The way that I display the profile is the same way shown by Facebook in their [Personalize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/) tutorial. This is working for my iPhone 4S running 5.1.1 and in the 5.1, 5.0 and 4.3 simulators.

The issue I'm having is I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` due to a null pointer in `FBDataDiskCache`'s `init` method when it calls: 
`dispatch_queue_t bgPriQueue = 
            dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        _fileQueue = dispatch_queue_create(
            "File Cache Queue", 
            DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        dispatch_set_target_queue(_fileQueue, bgPriQueue);`.

`bgPrigQueue` is null and I believe causing the issue. The `FBDataDiskCache` code is [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBDataDiskCache.m). Line 61 is the issue.

This bit of code is called when I try to set the `profileId` like so: `self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;`

I do think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary and the new SDK supports 4.0. So how do I get around this crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears  that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is only available in iOS 5.0 and later.

[Concurrent Queue with GCD? (iOS 4.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420599/concurrent-queue-with-gcd-ios-4-2-1)